# Adding parameters and backward compatibility?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, backwards-compatibility

Using WebAPI I have a restful service.

```
public SomeValue GetSomeValue()
{
}
```

I need to now pass in a string, but it's optional and a default value is fine:

```
public SomeValue GetSomeValue(string language="EN")
{
}
```

Will old clients that I can't update send a call just to `GetSomeValue()` still work, with a default value sent in? Or do I need to create a second method `GetSomeValueForLanguage(string language)` with `GetSomeValue()` calling it internally?

Comment: Can you try it in a test environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the method to take a default string parameter; old clients will be able to call it fine still, assuming your routing is staying the same (in which case `language` will be appended to the query string). If you're adding `language` as a route token, ensure that it's optional on the route such that the default parameter value for the action is used.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
public classs  MyParams
{
   public string language{set;get;}
}
```

then change you method to this:

```
public SomeValue GetSomeValue([FromBody] MyParams obj)
{
     if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.language) obj.language="en";
     //you code
}
```

if your HTTP method is GET, you shall use `FormUrl` attribute instead of `FromBody` attribute